# Where does the name 'Ens$_V$' come from?

Tags: category-theory, notation, terminology

The book I'm reading describes **Ens$_V$** as:

Where $V$ is any set of sets, the category with objects all $X \in V$, and arrows all functions $X \rightarrow Y$, with the usual function composition.

- What does the name **Ens$_V$** come from?
- What is it short for?
- How do you refer to it in speech?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\*Ens\*\* stand for?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46147/what-does-ens-stand-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's short for "Ensemble" which is French for "set". I guess you can pronounce it as is natural for you, but just in case, the French pronunciation goes [ɑ̃sɑ̃bl], where [ɑ̃] can be found in the more well-known words "an" (year), "jambe" (leg), "sang" (blood), "temps" (time).