# ENS is an abbreviation of?...

Tags: soft-question, notation, category-theory

In CWM Mac Lane uses the term $\mathbf {ENS}$  for a category having as objects the subsets of a given set and as morphisms the functions from these sets to these sets. What is abbreviated by the letters ENS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46147/what-does-ens-stand-for, might also like to see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/the-categories-set-and-ens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe ENS stands for ensembles, which means sets in French.

Comment: Incidentally, it also stands for École Normale Supérieure...